# Correct method of getting phone numbers from ABRecord

Tags: objective-c, macos, abaddressbook, abrecord

I am trying to get the phone numbers from an ABRecord object, and it is currently not working. Here is the code I am trying

```
ABRecord *record = contactsArr[row];

NSString *home;
NSString *iPhone;
NSString *main;
NSString *work;
NSString *mobile;

ABMutableMultiValue *multiValue = [record valueForProperty:kABPhoneProperty];
ABMutableMultiValue *multiValue2 = [record valueForProperty:kABPhoneHomeLabel];
ABMutableMultiValue *multiValue3 = [record valueForProperty:kABPhoneiPhoneLabel];
ABMutableMultiValue *multiValue4 = [record valueForProperty:kABPhoneMainLabel];
ABMutableMultiValue *multiValue5 = [record valueForProperty:kABPhoneMobileLabel];
ABMutableMultiValue *multiValue6 = [record valueForProperty:kABPhoneWorkLabel];

if ([multiValue valueAtIndex:0]) {
        numberString = [multiValue valueAtIndex:0];
}

if ([multiValue3 valueAtIndex:0]) {
            iPhone = [multiValue valueAtIndex:0];
        }
```

These are the errors I am getting in the output.

```
[7260:278597] -[ABPerson valueForProperty:_$!<Home>!$_] - unknown property. This    warning will be displayed only once per unknown property, per session.
[7260:278597] -[ABPerson valueForProperty:iPhone] - unknown property. This warning will be displayed only once per unknown property, per session.
[7260:278597] -[ABPerson valueForProperty:_$!<Main>!$_] - unknown property. This warning d[7260:278597] -[ABPerson valueForProperty:_$!<Mobile>!$_] - unknown property. This warning will be displayed only once per unknown property, per session.
[7260:278597] -[ABPerson valueForProperty:_$!<Work>!$_] - unknown property. This warning will be displayed only once per unknown property, per session.
```

What is the correct way of getting the phone numbers for each type of phone record from an ABRecord/Person? I can currently get it from the regular phone number but not from the specifics.